# uploading file from amazon hosted site to other ftp server

Tags: azure, amazon-ec2

I have one site hosted on Amazon EC2 instance. from this site(page) I am trying to upload the file to FTP server(not hosted with Amazon). everytime I am getting the error message that client connection has forcefully closed by remotehost.

same code is working fine in my local and few other local machine out side my office networks.

this code is not working from Amazon/Azure servers.

I have open all the ports and traffic for inbound/outbound ports

can somebody help me to understand the issue.

my server is windows 2012 r2 server.

all the traffic is open for in/out. 
site is developed in asp.net with unlimited ftp web control.

ftp server is supporting active mode and working from local machines in my networks and few other machines.

Thanks,
Devang

Answer (score 1):

Confirm you can connect via FTP from your EC2 instance without using your code. If you can connect via command line, or with an FTP app, then you know it's an issue with your code (and not some other IP-blocking issue).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to connect to that server using filezilla in active transfer mode. I have set the same in the code also but unable to upload the file.

please find the code below.

// Register handler to CommandResponse event.
            myclient.CommandResponse += client_CommandResponse;

```
        // Connect to the server.


        myclient.Passive = false;
        myclient.Connect(host, port);
        myclient.KeepAliveDuringTransferInterval = 5000;
        myclient.Timeout = 200000;


        // Authenticate.
        myclient.Authenticate(username, password);

        // Upload the file.
        myclient.UploadFile(serverFilePath, ComponentPro.IO.FileSystemPath.Combine(rootfolder, fileUpload.FileName));

        // Disconnect when finish.
        myclient.Disconnect();
        lblResult.Text = _sb.ToString();
```

Thanks for the help.